# php data send to javascript problem

Tags: javascript

php echo's <br /> to emphazise the javascript view to put a newline but when it comes to the javascript size it comes as &lt. br / &gt. and it is just displayed as it is. How can i send a <br /> as it is to the javascript size ?

the string that php sends

```
hello <br /> world
```

but javascript receives it as

```
hello &lt;br /&gt; world
```

How can i make javascript to understand a new line ?

echo "hello <br /> world";

sends the data to javascript

even

echo "hello \n world";

doesnt work

the javascript side

```
var txt = ajaxRequest.responseText;
$("#output tr td div").text(txt);
```

Comment: We need more context. You only described side effects, twice.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Exactly how is your php code "sending" the string to JavaScript?

Comment: it echos the string to javascript

Comment: That does not really make sense.

Comment: Can you see &lt in view-source tool or you are trying to append data to document with JavaScript? Show the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your updated answer, change your code from:

```
var txt = ajaxRequest.responseText;
$("#output tr td div").text(txt);
```

to (note the .html):

```
var txt = ajaxRequest.responseText;
$("#output tr td div").html(txt);
```

and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so from your previous answers it looks like your doing an ajax req? It should look like this (if you're using PHP, JavaScript and JQuery):

PHP side (some_file.php):

```
<?php
$out = "hello\nworld";

echo json_encode($out);
exit;
?>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function do_ajax() {
    $.get('some_file.php', {}, function (res) {
        // Res will be "hello\nworld";
        alert(res);
    }, 'json');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make new line in JavaScript string, right?
So PHP code:

```
echo "var asd = 'hello\\nworld';";
```

or

```
echo 'var asd = \'hello\nworld\';';
```

will result this:

```
var asd = 'hello\nworld';
```

You can now show effects with alert:

```
alert(asd);
```

which will show:

```
hello
world
```

That is new line in JavaScript.

Comment: var txt = ajaxRequest.responseText;
$("#output tr td div").text(txt); this is how the javascript prints it

Comment: If you want to use html tag use `.html()` method. If you want to use newline character use `.text()`. But remember, `"\n"` in PHP will print out newline character to the JavaScript document, but you want to have `\n` in JavaScript, so in PHP use single quotes or escape the backslash, just like i showed in example above.

Comment: But despite everything I think you should learn a little bit more of PHP and jQuery yet. Problems like this will be occurring all the time.

Answer (score -1):

Should be as simple as using `decodeURI(var)`.

Comment: No, that's not URI encoding, that's HTML escaping.

Comment: True, I guess I was thinking at something else. :)